# HTML / CSS Website - Disabling scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, window, border

I don't want this scroll bar being here. I don't want it hidden but I want it disabled. No scrolling at all.

A screenshot: https://gyazo.com/22224e178263f80c25ecabb65c8ff77f.png

index.html and stylesheet.css:

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="white">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


CSS:
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #272C34;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

#white {
    width: 100%;
    height: 76%;
    background-color: #E8E8E7;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: PLease post your code in your question so we can help.

Comment: You should just be able to copy and paste it. You can format it slightly, if its badly formatted, someone might edit it for you. Screen shots of code are pretty hard to work with!

Comment: Fixed it! 
Solution:

Set the padding of the element it's in to 0px;

Answer (score 0):

It is Problem of browser set default padding/margin. Apply any of CSS Reset to the website .

If Don't Add any one of them find here http://www.cssreset.com/

or Use this Universal CSS reset

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`body` usually has a margin set it, remove it and your div should be 100% of the screen:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also be aware that more tags have margins/paddings applied by default, you could use a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to remove margins/paddings/etc to make your page render the same on all browsers:

Answer (score 0):

if You mean Space in right and left in your Tmp. Add this to your Style

```
Body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<li>
<ul>
Hello
</ul>
</li>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
margin: 0;
}
#nav{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: #000000;
}

#nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
color:#ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**See it** [Live](http://jsfiddle.net/9w7s7xm2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use: width: 100vw; overflow-X: hidden;

This should work. When there is a scrollbar, use overflow-X:hidden for width or overflow-y:hidden for height;

Comment: Does this work? I'm not sure that setting the *width* to 100% of the viewport *height* is intentional here

Comment: You're right, my bad. I've corrected it. I meant 100vw; Point taken